# Approximating bounded measurable sets by compact sets from the inside: reference needed

Tags: measure-theory

Does anyone know a precise reference on the following assertion? (The question has already been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140130).)

Let $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure, and let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be $m$-measurable and bounded. Then, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact set $K_{\varepsilon}\subset A$ such that $m(A\setminus K_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$.

Many thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: See baby Rudin Chapter 10 statement 10.11

Comment: This property of the Lebesgue measure is called *inner-Regularity*.

Comment: @Norbert I think you mean chapter 11? (this is the case for the third edition at least).

Comment: I use Russian edition, this the reason of difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's just the kind of reference I've been searching for.