# Approximating measurable sets of infinite measure by open sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Following a question posted here:
**[Approximating measures by open sets and compact sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140130/approximating-measures-by-open-sets-and-compact-sets)**

I wanted to ask, if I am given a measurable set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $m(E)=\infty$, then how can I find an open set $O\supseteq E$ s.t. $m(O- E)<\epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: What's your definition of measurable?

Comment: Use caratheodory. A set $A$ is measurable iff $m*(A)=m*(A\cap E)+m*(A\cap E^c)$ for every subset $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's not at all clear what it means to "find" such a set. It's a theorem that it exists...

Comment: To show there exists such set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the formulation of your question, I assume that you already know the claim for sets of finite measure.

Now, for $n\in \Bbb{N}$, there is an open set $O_n \subset (-n,n)$ with $O_n \supset E_n := E\cap(-n,n)$ and $\mu(O_n \setminus E) = \mu(O_n \setminus E_n)<\epsilon/2^n$. Here,I used $O_n \subset (-n,n)$ to get the first equality.

Now, $O:=\bigcup O_n$ is open with $O\supset E$ (why?) and
$$
\mu (O\setminus E)\leq \sum_n \mu(O_n \setminus E)\leq \sum_n \epsilon/2^n \leq \epsilon.
$$

Comment: why is it important to assume $O_n\subset (-n,n)$? If we do not assume that, we have μ(On∖E)<μ(On∖En)<ϵ/2n and it is still valid

Comment: @User666x: You are right (if we replace "$<$" by "$\leq $"). I somehow thought we would need that property, but in fact we don't.